# get handle of IAccessible element

Tags: c++

I'm using `CComQIPtr<IAccessible> pAcc;` in C++
when i have found the right element, i want to get it's handle to use in SendMessage function, but i dont know how to get its handle or how to use it in SendMessage.
How to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`WindowFromAccessibleObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to get the `HWND` (which `SendMessage` expects) for a given `IAccessible`.